# firebase function returned undefined expected Promise or Value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

my code looks like below. it throws the error where i am returning null in both the cases. Should i return null in the end of the function as well? i was afraid if that will make function not to wait finishing

```
exports.on_user_created_update_generate_barcode = functions.database.ref("/users/{id}")
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    console.log("start of on_user_created_update_generate_barcode ")   
    const user = snapshot.val();
    const referralCode = user._referralCode
    const uid = context.params.id
    console.log("Referral code is:" + referralCode + " for user:" + uid)



    bwipjs.toBuffer({
        bcid:        'code128',       // Barcode type
        text:        referralCode,    // Text to encode
        scale:       3,               // 3x scaling factor
        height:      10,              // Bar height, in millimeters
        includetext: true,            // Show human-readable text
        textxalign:  'center',        // Always good to set this
    }, function (err, png) {
        if (err) {
            console.err("failed to generate bar code:::" + err)
            return null
        } else {
            console.log("png generated")
            //console.log(png)
            const pngImg = 'data:image/png;base64,' + png.toString('base64')
            var db = admin.database();
            var userRef = db.ref('users')
            return userRef.child(uid).update({"_barcode": pngImg})
        }
    });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct - you are are not returning anything from your function, which is the same as returning `undefined`.  What you are doing instead is return null from a function callback that you passed to `bwipjs.toBuffer()`.  The return value of that inner function does not propagate to the outer function.

If you just return null from the top level of your function, you may stop that error messages, but the code will not work correctly.  Cloud Functions will shut down all asynchronous work that was started inside the function after the function returns a value that's not a promise.  It will likely appears to do nothing at all.

What you will need to do is return a promise that resolves when all the asynchronous work is complete in your function.  Right now, that looks like the call to `toBuffer()`, and also the `update()` to Realtime Database.

You might find the [documentation on async programming](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) in functions helpful.  You may also want to watch this [video series on dealing with promises in Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/).

Comment: your explanation makes sense. how to convert it to promise that way?

Comment: It's not a simple "conversion".  You need to write your code in a way that makes use of promises in the way that I described.